# Fixest::feols: Using sw with interaction or using map to output multiple RHS versions of a model

Tags: r

I am trying to output multiple versions of a model using fixest::feols. My goal is to run the model independently for each restriction column in my dataset and either get a list or etable of all the regression summaries. The tricky part is that I am interacting the restriction variable with Year, and I am not sure how to use sw() within the i() functionality of fixest. I also tried writing a function and using map to output the models by feeding it a list, but I ran into trouble there as well with my limited knowledge of NSE. Here is a simplified version of my dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(Year = rep(2000:2007), fipscode = c("001", "002"), 
                 conditional_ban = rep(0:1), registration = rep(0:1), pct = rnorm(n = 16, mean = .02, sd = .005))
```

There are two ways I have tried to go about doing this. The first is using sw() within feols:

```
require(fixest)

res <- feols(fml = pct ~ 
                     i(sw(registration, conditional_ban), Year) | factor(Year) + factor(fipscode), 
             data = df)

etable(res)
```

This produces the error: "You cannot combine stepwise functions with any other
element." Upon that discovery, I tried to create a function for my model and then using it in map:

```
# function that takes a restriction as its argument and results in a table summary with the name 
# of the restriction 
model_restr <- function(restr){
        mod <- eval(substitute(feols(fml = pct ~
                                             i(restr, Year) | factor(Year) +
                                             factor(fipscode), 
                                     data = df)))
        modsum <- summary(mod)
        varName <- deparse(substitute(restr))
        . <- etable(modsum, signifCode = c("***" = 0.01, "**" = 0.05, "*" = 0.1))
        assign(varName, ., envir = globalenv())
}

# Then, I create a list with the restrictions
restrs <- list(names = c("conditional_ban", "registration")

# Next, I try to use map to loop the function over the list
map(restrs$names, model_restr)
```

This results in the error: "Error in feols(fml = pct ~ i(.x[[i]], Year) | factor(Year) +  : The variables '.x' and 'i' are in the RHS (first part) of the formula but not in the data set."

Now, I understand that I am feeding a quoted argument to the function model_restr, and I've tried to use !! or noquote() to unquote the argument like this:

```
 model_restr <- function(restr){
        restr <- noquote(restr)
        mod <- eval(substitute(feols(fml = pct ~
                                             i(restr, Year) | factor(Year) +
                                             factor(fipscode), 
                                     data = df)))
        modsum <- summary(mod)
        varName <- deparse(substitute(restr))
        . <- etable(modsum, signifCode = c("***" = 0.01, "**" = 0.05, "*" = 0.1))
        assign(varName, ., envir = globalenv())
}
```

I know I am probably missing something important here when it comes to NSE, but I cannot figure out what exactly is going wrong. I am pretty new to R and programming, but I am eager to understand this so that I can speed up my workflow. I appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply insert the `i()`s into the `sw()` and that will do:

```
data(base_did) ; base = base_did
# Alternative treatment indicator, purely random
base$treat_bis = 1 * (base$id %in% sample(108, 50))

# 2 estimations
res = feols(y ~ sw(i(treat, period, 5), i(treat_bis, period, 5)) | id + period, base)
etable(res)
#>                                  model 1         model 2
#> Dependent Var.:                        y               y
#>                                                         
#> treat x period = 1        -2.015 (1.342)                
#> treat x period = 2        -1.664 (1.389)                
#> treat x period = 3        0.5041 (1.323)                
#> treat x period = 4       -0.8846 (1.416)                
#> treat x period = 6         1.159 (1.227)                
#> treat x period = 7       4.335** (1.308)                
#> treat x period = 8        3.826* (1.514)                
#> treat x period = 9      4.640*** (1.293)                
#> treat x period = 10     6.947*** (1.426)                
#> treat_bis x period = 1                    -1.565 (1.358)
#> treat_bis x period = 2                    -1.200 (1.425)
#> treat_bis x period = 3                   -3.350* (1.301)
#> treat_bis x period = 4                   -3.538* (1.385)
#> treat_bis x period = 6                   -2.660* (1.227)
#> treat_bis x period = 7                    -2.274 (1.382)
#> treat_bis x period = 8                   -3.399* (1.529)
#> treat_bis x period = 9                   -2.724. (1.374)
#> treat_bis x period = 10                   -2.177 (1.615)
#> Fixed-Effects:          ---------------- ---------------
#> id                                   Yes             Yes
#> period                               Yes             Yes
#> _______________________ ________________ _______________
#> S.E.: Clustered                   by: id          by: id
#> Observations                       1,080           1,080
#> R2                               0.32343         0.26744
#> Within R2                        0.08710         0.01155
```

I took the liberty to change the example since the interactions were collinear with the fixed-effects.

By the way, `factor()` is not needed in the RHS of the pipe (it only makes the estimation slower).